# pt-table-sync fails "Turning off AutoCommit"

Tags: mysql, percona, percona-toolkit, perl

While trying to use pt-table-sync with the following options for a list of slaves:

```
pt-table-sync --print --replicate schema.checksum_table --sync-to-master slave-001
```

I receive the following error message on some of the slaves:

```
DBD::mysql::db STORE failed: Turning off AutoCommit failed at /usr/lib/perl5/DBI.pm line 723.
```

The MySQL version for the slave is 5.6.17 and for the master 5.6.15. Other slaves for which this does work also have MySQL 5.6.15 version.
I am able to turn off session autocommit if I log in to the slave directly using MySQL client and the same user being used for pt-table-sync.
The checksum table in use was created by previously running pt-table-checksum.

DBI.pm version:

```
perl -MDBI -e 'print "$DBI::VERSION\n";'
1.63
```

Has anyone encountered this issue before?

Please let me know if you need me to provide more information.

Comment: What version of `DBI.pm`?

Comment: Hi, I've just updated the post. The DBI.pm version is 1.63.

Comment: What version of `DBD::mysql`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the [bug is in your copy of DBD::mysql which seems to have been fixed](https://rt.cpan.org/Public/Bug/Display.html?id=83518) sometime before version 4.027. Make sure your copy of `DBD::mysql` is up to date. 4.041 was released in Nov of 2016.

```
cpan DBD::mysql
```